# GTM - Parse Google Analytics event_label into separate variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-events, data-layers, google-tag-manager-server-side

I work with a vendor that powers email capture experiences on my website. They have a productized solution that pushes events into GA4. Those events are pushed to the datalayer and they don't have the ability to customize the datalayer event.

Here is an example of what they push to GA.

event > "Overlay Impression"
event_category >  "Overlay Event"
event_label "Email Capture | Bottom Bar | All Pages | Need Some Planning"

I want set up triggers in GTM so that I can push these events into Segment and other Analytics platforms.

I'd like to get more granular in those platforms.

Is it possible to parse the event_label string into individual variables?

Desired outcome would be:

Variable Name | Value
event | Overlay Impression
event_category | Overlay Event
overlay_type | Email Capture
overlay_deplyoment | Bottom Bar
overlay_location | All Pages
overlay_copy | Need Some Planning

So far I'm just researching here to see if something similar has been done